# How to copy contents of system() command obtained text files in windows?

Tags: c, windows, file, copy, system

I'm trying to get the HDD serial number from the following code & also trying to copy the lines from the "HDDserial.txt" to another text file called "Bond.txt":

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
char ch;
FILE *fp1,*fp2;
system("wmic path win32_physicalmedia get SerialNumber > HDDserial.txt");
fp1 = fopen("HDDserial.txt","r");
fp2 = fopen("Bond.txt","w");
while((ch= fgetc(fp1)!= EOF))
{
    fputc(ch,fp2);
}
fputs("\nSender\n",fp2);
fclose(fp1);
fclose(fp2);

return 0;
}
```

I'm getting output of "HDDserial.txt" like this:

> SerialNumber
>   32534230394a5a44303333333931202020202020

but my "Bond.txt" gives me some peculiar characters.like this image:
[image: Image for "Bond.txt"]

But I want the same output as "HDDserial.txt" in "Bond.txt" ! 
Can anyone please help me with my codes?so that I can fix this problem & get done proper copying?

Comment: Why not just add a command in `system` to copy the file?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand that :(

Comment: `system("wmic path win32_physicalmedia get SerialNumber > HDDserial.txt && copy HDDserial.txt Bond.txt");`

Comment: Thanks that works!, But contents(sentences) in my output file "Bond.txt" is scattered and I can't perform `strcmp()` or similar character check operation on them...it returns error !

Answer (score 2):

`!=` binds tighter than `=`.

So this

```
ch = fgetc(fp1) != EOF
```

assigns the result of `fgetc(fp1) != EOF` to `ch`, which is `1` until `EOF` had been reached, which makes it `0`.

To correct this use parentheses like this:

```
(ch = fgetc(fp1)) != EOF
```

---

Also `fgetc()` returns `int` not `char`. So make `ch` an `int`.

```
int main()
{
  int ch;

  ...

  while ((ch = fgetc(fp1)) != EOF)
  {
    fputc((char) ch, fp2);
  }

  ...
```

Or introduce an intermediate variable:

```
int main()
{
  int result;

  ...

  while ((result = fgetc(fp1)) != EOF)
  {
    char ch = (char) result;
    fputc(ch, fp2);
  }

  ...
```

Comment: @Md.FakruddinGazzaliFahim: So you applied the changes as listed above and you get the *exact same* result as before? Really?

Comment: @Md.FakruddinGazzaliFahim: Delete all possible occurrences of `Bond.txt`and retry.

Comment: Also add error checking to the calls to `fopen()` and `system()`. `fgetc()` might fail as well.

Comment: I tried the process John told me, that works but sentences are scattered in that "Bond.txt" & sadly I can't perform `strcmp()` or similar character check operation on them...it returns error !